# True/false: There are $4$ linearly independent vectors $v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4 \in \mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors

> True/false: There are $4$ linearly independent vectors
>   $v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4 \in \mathbb{R}^3$.

I think the statement is true.

Let's take as example (**this is my own example, not of the task!!**):

$$a\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
0\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix}+b\begin{pmatrix}
0\\ 
1\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix}+c\begin{pmatrix}
0\\ 
0\\ 
1
\end{pmatrix}+d\begin{pmatrix}
0\\ 
0\\ 
1
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
0\\ 
0\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix}$$

We get that $a=b=0$

Now if $c=0$, then $d=0$, but of course we cannot know that in this case. We have to know it..?

Anyway you can see I'm not sure : /

Comment: What about if $c=1$?

Comment: @ShaVuklia Then the vectors would be linearly dependent because we would have $1 = -1$, and we have that $a=b=0$

Comment: @tenepolis: are you familiar with the dimension of a vector space?

Comment: @student No. But I believe the dimension of the vectors are $4$ but we are in dimension $3$ and there is some kind of mismatch.. So it's impossible they are linearly independent..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vectors are linearly independent if their weighted sum (linear combination) is zero if and only if all the weights are $0$s.

This is not the case in the OP:

$$0\cdot\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
0\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix}+0\cdot\begin{pmatrix}
0\\ 
1\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix}+(-1)\cdot\begin{pmatrix}
0\\ 
0\\ 
1
\end{pmatrix}+(+1)\cdot\begin{pmatrix}
0\\ 
0\\ 
1
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
0\\ 
0\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix}.$$

That is, the vectors above are not linearly independet.

**So, the statement is false.**

Above, we only showed that the example four-tuple was linearly dependent. [But, it is true in general](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence#Vectors_in_R2) that in $R^3$ only three (or less) linearly independent vectors can be singled out.

Comment: it was stated in the answer informally, that there are only 3 linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ but it is actually an elementary theorem of linear algebra that any set of $m$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is linearly dependent if $m>n$.

Answer (score 2):

Assume $\vec v_1,\vec v_2,\vec v_3$ are linearly independent in $\mathbb{R^3}$. Then they form a basis, and we have that:
$$a\vec v_1+b\vec v_2+c\vec v_3=\vec x$$

for any $\vec x\in\mathbb{R^3}$ and for some $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}$, and therefore includes any $\vec v_4\in\mathbb{R^3}$.

Comment: he might not know that any basis has the same size

Answer (score 1):

In your choice: $v_3=v_4$. Hence $v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4$ are linearly dependent:

$0=v_3-v_4$.

Comment: I also like to know if the statement is true or false, please let me know if you know.

Comment: The statement is false ! In $ \mathbb R^3$ we have: $4$ vecors are always linearly dependent.